# Composer create-project always fails with the project I created

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I have this project on Github and Packagist:

https://github.com/gitraffa/framework

https://packagist.org/packages/gitraffa/framework

I want to use this as a deploy app, so, when I need to start a new project I just go to the cmd and type `composer create-project gitraffa/framework --prefer-dist`and it should automatically create the folder and inser the files. But it isn't working(I always get something saying that a stable version could not be found). Am I doing something wrong or can't this be done?

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "gitraffa/framework",
    "description": "A powerful yet easy-to-use PHP micro-framework designed to help you build dynamic and robust Web applications - fast!",
    "homepage": "http://rafaelmsantos.com/",
    "license": "GPL-3.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rafael Santos",
            "email": "dev.rafael@mail.com",
            "homepage": "http://rafaelmsantos.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.6",
        "psr/log": "~1.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/gitraffa/framework"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer by default installs only tagged versions (last stable that meets condition).

The error message can be fixed by:

1. using @dev tag, like: `composer create-project gitraffa/framework:@dev --prefer-dist`
2. tagging your package

Comment: "minimum-stability": "dev" using this, and then at the branch-alias use "1.0.-dev" ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to tag my project, please? (sorry for asking, but this is very complicated and I can't search any answer that helps me)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't understand your note. By tagging I meant [git tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). For. e.g. `git tag v0.1.0 && git push --tags`

Comment: That should do the trick, I'll investigate a bit more and try to do that. Thanks my friend.